# pandas group by 3 variables but sum over 2 of them

Tags: python, pandas

I have a data frame :

```
In [59]: df.head()
Out[59]: 

       src-subnet        dst-subnet  bytes       Start
0             ATL          Internet    180  1477252800
1             ATL               ATL    206  1477252800
2             ATL  Private-10.0.0.0  17160  1477252800
3             SAT          Internet  15768  1477252800
4  AWS-CloudFront               ATL   1592  1477252800
```

for each value of start I want the sum of the bytes that are transmitted between each possible pair of `src-subnet` and `dst-subnet`.

I wrote the following:

```
g_start = df.groupby('Start')
g_start_subnet = g_start.apply(lambda x: x.groupby(['src-subnet', 'dst-subnet']).sum())
```

and I obtained:

```

```
In [60]: g_start_subnet
Out[60]: 

                                                               bytes
Start      src-subnet          dst-subnet                           
1476896400 ATL                 ATL                        5190647907
                               AWS                             67442
                               AWS-CloudFront                3523866
                               AWS-EC2                      10231320
                               Broadcast-255.255.255.255      550470
                               COL                          25459487
                               Corvil-CNE                       5130
                               DEN                          68247258
                               DFB                          49930518
                               DFW                         109329393
                               HOU                          43601191
                               IND                          97444445
                               Internal Network              2295849
                               Internet                     72555057
                               JES                          64789642
                               LAF                          30442304
                               LOU                           27372802
                               MGO                            307340
                               Multicast-224.0.0.0          25339730
                               NOL                          49526023
                               Private-10.0.0.0            814280925
                               Private-172.16.0.0            9348122
                               Private-192.168.0.0           8907521
                               SAT                          43590577
                               SCI                           2473674
                               WMSApp                       74085307
                               WMSDB                         9604726
           AWS                 ATL                             78309
           AWS-CloudFront      ATL                          10026686
                               HOU                              9285
...                                                              ...
1477497600 Private-10.0.0.0    Internet                     90581028
                               Link-169.254.0.0                  276
                               Private-10.0.0.0            159103776
                               Private-192.168.0.0          60724723
                               WMSApp                           1100
           Private-100.64.0.0  ATL                           1304731
           Private-192.168.0.0 ATL                             77031
                               Internet                          926
                               Multicast-224.0.0.0            238220
                               Private-10.0.0.0                19320
                               Private-192.168.0.0            393982
           SAT                 ATL                          18278815
                               AWS-EC2                         28380
                               Internet                     42773386
                               Private-10.0.0.0              8030664
                               Private-172.16.0.0             230389
                               Private-192.168.0.0           5938773
           SCI                 ATL                           2055407
                               Internet                          900
                               Multicast-224.0.0.0               256
           Solace-Servers      Broadcast-255.255.255.255      153438
           WMSApp              ATL                          95861882
                               AWS-EC2                           360
                               DFB                              3066
                               DFW                              9000
                               Internet                         3330
                               Multicast-224.0.0.0          31292117
                               Private-10.0.0.0                 1022
           WMSDB               ATL                           8678562
                               Internet                         2160
```

How can I know remove the multiindex and obtain a matrix like dataframe?

The final result should have the columns `Start, bytes, src-subnet, dst-subnet`

Comment: thanks it's working. Do you think the rest of the code is fine?

Comment: It is non typical, please check if output is same as `print (df.groupby(['Start', 'src-subnet', 'dst-subnet'], as_index=False).sum())`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can use:

```
g_start_subnet = g_start_subnet.reset_index()
```

But maybe better is use:

```
print (df.groupby(['Start', 'src-subnet', 'dst-subnet'], as_index=False).sum())
```